# Proper way to create a simple HTTP serve app

Tags: c#

I want to create a very simple C# app that does a job every time a certain http request is sent to it. It may receive a ton of requests at any given time. So far I can do this with a basic console app and an `HttpListener`, but I have to hold the app open with a `Console.Readline()`. Obviously this is A way to go, but is it THE way to go? It seems a little hacky to me, and I'm new to C#, so I'm wondering if there is a best practice for this or if I should be using a different .NET approach like MVC.

Comment: [Getting Started with ASP.NET Web API 2 (C#)](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api)

Comment: Would a web api be suitable for something like file uploads? Basically this app will receive an http request with a file path in it, and the app will then upload that file from the local server file system to amazon s3. Would a web api scale well doing this sort of thing?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is a Web Service. Have a look at this simple example of how it works: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308359